# Is there a react native library that allow a server to make web requests using the client app as https proxy?

Tags: android, react-native, proxy

I'm messing around with some cross-platform application development, and I am wondering if there is a way to proxy certain server 2 server requests through an android (or iOS) application.

In more detail, the workflow I have in mind is as follows:

- The user opens the app and click on a "data update" button
- The app sends a request to the server informing that "data update" has been requested and that the app can be used as a proxy
- The server, using an external API, contacts other servers to retrieve data using the client as proxy. All the traffic is routed through the phone.
- The user click on a "display results" button and the server sends the computed response

The only reason I'm doing this in React Native is because I would like the app to be cross-platform, but if you know some native library that can be used to do something similar, I would love to hear about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't manage to find such a library.
What I did was to:

1. Launch a proxy server

   This server receives all the information that needs to be forwarded by the client. I used the library "web-sniffer", but anyone will do the tricks. The proxy needs to change the host target address to be the address of the Server in point 2.
2. Launch a web server

   This server needs to receive the requests from the proxy and forward them to the client using a web socket in point 3.
3. Launch a web socket

   This server needs to receive a connection from the app client (point 4) and then send the requests received from the web server to the app client.
4. Create an application client

   This application needs to create a socket connection with the socket server (point 3). Upon receiving a message, it should create a web request using the received data (I used axios as library) and upon response it should send back the response to the web socket (point 2), which in turn should create a response for the original request using the client response, which then is received by the application who initially used the proxy (point 1).